# Polymorphic generics (or something similar)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm not really sure how to word what I want, so I'll just show the code that isn't working:

```
abstract class EventListener<T> where T : IEvent
{
}

interface IEvent
{
}

/*
 * Simplified a bit, normally this class would use a dictionary of event listeners
 */
class Manager
{
    private EventListener<IEvent> listener;

    public void RegisterListener<T>(EventListener<T> subject) where T : IEvent
    {
        // here is the issue
        listener = subject;
    }
}

/*
 *  Implementation
 */

class FooEvent : IEvent
{
}

class FooListener : EventListener<FooEvent>
{
}
```

The issue occurs when I try to assign `subject` to `listener`. I tried casting before assigning, but had a similar problem:

```
EventListener<IEvent> casted = subject as EventListener<IEvent>;
events.Add(typeof(T), casted);
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Could you add members of `EventListener<T>` and `Event` in your post? Also, please, add a prefix to an interface name (`IEvent` instead of `Event`).

Comment: @Dennis I've fixed the names, but I don't think it's necessary to add members at this point, since the issue has already been solved. I'm trying to keep this post as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add non-generic interface `IEventListener`:

   ```
   interface IEventListener
   { }
   ```
2. Implement it by your `EventListener<T>` class:

   ```
    abstract class EventListener<T> : IEventListener where T : IEvent
   {
   }
   ```
3. Change your `Manager.listener` field type to `IEventListener`:

   ```
   private IEventListener listener;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be that simple.